# Get access to photos' tags on Facebook with Graph API

Tags: facebook, permissions

It's possible to get access for tags on friends' photo from facebook app? Lets assume I have **friends_photos** permission.

edit:

If yes, how to do it using Graph API? How would I know on which photo is tag I have got from Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL the [photo_tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) table.

You can graph FQL with:`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY`
Read more on [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

take a look at:

```
photos.getTags    // Returns the set of user tags for all photos specified.
```

more at:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.getTags/

Comment: It is some clue. I edited my question. Please answer if you know.